# When creating a LaunchConfigurationTab how do I get the 'apply' button to highlight?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, launch-configuration

I have the necessary extension points and my Tab class is extending `AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.` I am doing nothing different to examples, such as, the `CommonTab`. I call `updateLaunchConfigurationDialog()` when a widget event is fired.

EDIT: The listener method for my widgets are definitely being called and the `performApply` method is being called. I am doing what the `CommonTab` class does with one of its radio buttons, for example:

```java
fSharedRadioButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent evt) {
            handleSharedRadioButtonSelected();
        }
    });

/**
 * handles the shared radio button being selected
 */
private void handleSharedRadioButtonSelected() {
    setSharedEnabled(isShared());
    updateLaunchConfigurationDialog();
}
```

The only difference is that my widget is a spinner:

```java
executionsSpinner.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            updateLaunchConfigurationDialog();
        }
    });
```

Comment: We'll need more info, e.g what did you try, how did you try to debug it etc.

Comment: Your `performApply` method must update values in the working configuration copy using the various `setAttribute` methods.

Answer (score 1):

When `updateLaunchConfigurationDialog` is called the framework triggers a call to your tab's `performApply` method.

`performApply` is passed an `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy` instance as an argument. When `performApply` returns that `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy` instance is compared with the original, unmodified `ILaunchConfiguration`. If there are any differences then the *Apply* button is enabled.

You must hence make some modification to the argument of `performApply` for *Apply*  to be enabled, just as Greg notices in their comment.